# One out of two rules not firing

Tags: java, drools, priority-queue, rule-engine

I'm kinda beginner to JAVA and Drools in particular, so don't ask why i'm doing this :D The task was to implement a simple system that will calculate tariffs and prices of 2 items (different colors). I made a simple class with getters and setters :

```
package com.sample;

public class Pen {

    private String color;
    private int quantity;
    private double tariff;
    private double subTotal;

    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color=color;
    }

    public int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity){
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public double getTariff(){
        return tariff;
    }

    public void setTariff(double tariff){
        this.tariff=tariff;
    }

    public double getSubTotal(){
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(double subTotal){
        this.subTotal=subTotal;
    }

}
```

Task was to read some predefined data from a CSV file and write it to another CSV (writing not yet implemented). Class that processes the input and calls the session is as follows :

```
public class CSVReader {
    public void CSVToJava() {
        String CSVFile = "csvExample.csv";
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        String line = "";
        String delimiter = ",";
        List<Pen> penList = new ArrayList<Pen>();

        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
            StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVFile));
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] pens = line.split(delimiter);
                Pen redPen = new Pen();
                Pen bluePen = new Pen();
                if (pens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Blue Pen")) {
                    bluePen.setColor(pens[0]);
                    bluePen.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(pens[1].trim()));
                    penList.add(bluePen);
                    ksession.insert(bluePen);
                } else {
                    redPen.setColor(pens[0]);
                    redPen.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(pens[1].trim()));
                    penList.add(redPen);
                    ksession.insert(redPen);
                }
            }
            ksession.fireAllRules();
            printPenList(penList);        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (buffer != null) {
                try {
                    buffer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printPenList(List<Pen> penListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < penListToPrint.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(penListToPrint.get(i).getColor() + "," + penListToPrint.get(i).getQuantity() + ","
                    + penListToPrint.get(i).getTariff() + "," + penListToPrint.get(i).getSubTotal());
        }

    }

    private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {

        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/Drools/BluePen.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/Drools/RedPen.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);

        KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();

        if (errors.size() > 0) {
            for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors) {
                System.err.println(error);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
        }

        KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());

        return kbase;
    }

}
```

I also have 2 separate DRL files, for each item color. Based on the calculation of the rules, i need to print out 2 additional properties, simple multiplications (subTotal). Each file has 2 rules :

```
import com.sample.Pen; //FIRST ONE

rule "less or equal to 10"

    when
        item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE PEN"), (item.getQuantity()) <= 10.0)
    then
        item.setTariff(3.0);
        item.setSubTotal(3.0 * ((double) item.getQuantity()));      
end

rule "more than 10"
    when
        item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE PEN"), (item.getQuantity()) > 10.0)
    then
        item.setTariff(2.5);
        item.setSubTotal(2.5 * ((double) item.getQuantity()));
end



import com.sample.Pen; //SECOND ONE


rule "less or equal to 10"

        when
            item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("RED PEN"), (item.getQuantity()) <= 10.0)
        then
            item.setTariff(3.5);
            item.setSubTotal(3.5 * ((double) item.getQuantity()));      
    end

    rule "more than 10"
        when
            item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("RED PEN"),   (item.getQuantity()) > 10.0)
        then
            item.setTariff(3.0);
            item.setSubTotal(3.0 * ((double) item.getQuantity()));
    end
```

Also, there is a class where i call the whole method for starting the process :

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
          csvReader.CSVToJava();
    }

}
```

Everything looks like this [packageExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL0X5.png)

My main problem is that the printout looks like this -->

```
Red Pen,6,3.5,21.0
Blue Pen,12,0.0,0.0
```

Each row should consist of 4 fields, first two are calculated int he CSVReader class in while loop, while the last two (3.5 and 21.0 in the case or Red Pen) are calculated with Drools. As you can see, rules for the blue pen are not firing at all and i cannot solve the problem... If someone could help, i would be more than thankful :)

EDIT: After solving this, I edited the code with another 3 rule spread over 2 DRL files :

```
package com.drools //First.drl

import com.sample.Pen;

rule "Subtotal for blue pen" salience 2

    when
        item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE PEN"))
    then
        item.setTotal(item.getTotal() + item.getSubTotal());    
end

rule "Subtotal for red pen" salience 2

    when
        item : Pen(item.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("RED PEN"))
    then
        item.setTotal(item.getTotal() + item.getSubTotal());    
end


package com.drools //Second.drl

import com.sample.Pen;

rule "Discounted total price" salience 1

    when
        item : Pen((item.getTotal()) > 100.0)
    then
        item.setTotal(0.85 * item.getTotal());
end
```

I have added the file classpaths inside my session also, in order to be fireable. When the fireAll method is invoked, there is no rule firing for the second drl fire, where the total amount is being multiplied by 0.85 (`total` is a static variable declared inside the `Pen` class, so I could collect the addition of  `suTotal`s from each color), eventhough salience is the lowest --> should fire last and the correct amount should be 140*0.85 = 119.

Looks like this :

```
Red Pen,30,3.0,90.0
Blue Pen,20,2.5,50.0
140
```

Maybe someone can figure this out also, you guys have been great so far with the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both files have rules

```
rule "less or equal to 10"
rule "more than 10"
```

You can't have that. Rules are identified by name; a rule with the same name as another one will silently overwrite the first one. Load order from different DRL files is undefined.

There was a long discussion whether and how this should work during Drools 5.x, but this is now water under the bridge and you'll have to stick with it. (I'm not sure whether Drools 6.x permits this. Consult the docs.)

Thanks to @Wis for confirming that Drools 6.x raises an compilation error when there are rules with identical names in a compilation, irrespective of being in the same DRL file or in different files.

Comment: Made a test to be sure for Drools 6.x : It does not permit duplicate names. It does end up with : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: [4,0]: Duplicate rule name: less or equal to 10 [12,0]: Duplicate rule name: more than 10`. I'll edit your post for completeness.

Comment: @Wis Before you do, make sure that there's no difference between the rules being in the same or in different files.

Comment: Another problem occured, also with rules firing, I have edited the post with details. Seems like salience is not working properly or I'm missing something :-/

Comment: You are missing fundamental things. First, read about modify & update.  Second, using static (class) variables is an excellent way of creating mischief. You have two Pen objects - the total is visible through both, so for a total of 140 the rule would fire once for the red and then for the blue pen, resulting 140*0.85*0.85. Third, avoid salience unless you are absolutely sure you can't do without.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think im going to leave that part out since i dont have much time left to go further into it.

Comment: @laune I tested and can confirm the IllegalStateException for duplicate rule name is raised in both situation : two rules with same name in a single file and in two different files (assuming the two DRL files are in the same compilation).

Comment: To be even more precise, Drools 6.x do not raise the `IllegalStateException`, the exception comes from the `readKnowledgeBase()` method written in the original question. The errors are to be retrieved in `kbuilder.getErrors()`.

Comment: @Wis Ah! I was slightly irritated when I wrote that, but, being under stress didn't really think it through. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert, but I would suggest to switch RED PEN and BLUE PEN to see if it is not triggering the rules after first rule. or it could be problem with CSV file reading. thx

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i agree, but I am not allowed to comment with my current points.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison in rules conditions should not use Java equals method. Drools is using its own [rule language](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html). (But take care - 5.x syntax is somewhat more restricted than what is shown in the referenced document. And it also varies between minor versions, 5.2/3/... [laune])

Have a look at example 4.4 (I corrected the missing `"` in the example) :

```
1: rule simple_rule
2:   when
3:     Student( name == "Andy" )
4:   then
5: end
```

You should try this syntax for your rules (also note that your quantity is an integer and not a float) :

```
when
    item : Pen(color == "BLUE PEN", quantity > 10)
```

As a side note, your `(double)` casts in the action part of your rules are not mandatory. Multiplying a double and an integer in Java ends up with a double value, which is already the type of your tariff and subTotal members.

Comment: You can still use equals. And equalsIgnoreCase (as OP has it) is another method anyway.

Comment: You are right, equals does work. If i'm not mistaken, only a small subset of Java can be used in conditions. I remember being unable to use some of the `Calendar` methods. There is however a small difference, drools == operator is null safe.

Comment: I took the liberty and added a cautionary remark re the syntax between 6.x and 5.x versions.

Comment: The original question does not indicates which version of drools borgmater is using. Then being cautious when clicking on the link is needed. Your edit is relevant.